# Issue with overlapping bones

Tags: armature, bones, weight-painting, pose-mode

I have character model that have multiple objects and bones. Models were psk files.

[image]

I want to merge all bones in one armature but `ctrl+j` simply doesn't work. It just do overlapping bones.

Here picture of head part in pose mode. I think brown ones are unused bones and have no idea about green bone. Browns don't effect mesh in weight mode (They look purple in weight mode). So I can delete brown ones. White and green bones has weight paints.

[image]

In this picture bones in red circle are overlapping and have diffirent weight paints on their own meshes.

[image]

In these two images common bones and their weights are seen.

[image]
[image]

All meshes have common bones like in head and torso. The question is how can I merge bones with their weigths on diffirent meshes?

edit: all meshes imported from psk file => [image]